# Screenshot of Flutter Google Maps Widget shows blank page

Tags: flutter, google-maps, screenshot, riverpod

In my fruit-tree-management app, i want the user to take a screenshot of his garden based on the google maps location.
I can take a screenshot for it, but the screenshot appears to be blank, only showing the Google Sign on the left lower corner and the location-icon on the right lower corner.
What am I doing wrong?
Should i use a Stateful-Widget instead of my Stateless Widget combined with riverpod-state-management?

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fruit_tree_garden/src/features/garden/presentation/garden_detail_view.dart';
import 'package:fruit_tree_garden/src/features/home/presentation/add_garden_provider.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:screenshot/screenshot.dart';

class AddGardenMap extends HookConsumerWidget {
  static const routeName = '/add-garden-map';
  const AddGardenMap({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final Completer<GoogleMapController> mapController =
        Completer<GoogleMapController>();

    final addGardenMapState = ref.watch(addGardenProvider);

    Set<Polygon> polygons = addGardenMapState.polygon != null
        ? {
            addGardenMapState.polygon!,
          }
        : {};

    Set<Polyline> polylines = addGardenMapState.polygonPoints == null ||
            addGardenMapState.polygonPoints!.isEmpty
        ? {}
        : {
            Polyline(
              polylineId: const PolylineId('drawnLine'),
              points: addGardenMapState.polygonPoints ?? [],
              width: 2,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          };

    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 36, horizontal: 28),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (context, constraints) {
                int mapWidth = constraints.maxWidth.toInt();
                int mapHeight = constraints.maxHeight.toInt();

                return GoogleMap(
                  zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
                    mapController.complete(controller);
                    ref
                        .read(addGardenProvider.notifier)
                        .setMapController(controller);
                  },
                  initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
                    target: LatLng(50.914002, 12.6332654),
                    zoom: 18,
                  ),
                  mapType: MapType.normal,
                  onTap: (LatLng point) {
                    final addGardenProv = ref.read(addGardenProvider.notifier);
                    List<LatLng> currentPoints =
                        addGardenMapState.polygonPoints ?? [];

                    // Check if the new point is close to the first point
                    if (currentPoints.isNotEmpty &&
                        addGardenProv.isClose(point, currentPoints.first)) {
                      // Close the polygon by adding the first point at the end
                      currentPoints.add(currentPoints.first);
                      addGardenProv.setPolygon(currentPoints);
                      final bounds =
                          addGardenProv.getPolygonBounds(currentPoints);

                      _showConfirmationDialog(
                        context: context,
                        onRedraw: () async {
                          addGardenProv.reset();
                        },
                        onSave: () {},
                        ref: ref,
                      );
                    } else {
                      addGardenProv.setPoints(point);
                    }
                  },
                  polylines: polylines,
                  polygons: polygons,
                );
              },
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 15,
              right: 15.0,
              left: 15.0,
              child: TextField(
                onSubmitted: (address) {
                  ref.read(addGardenProvider.notifier).searchLocation(address);
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Enter Garden Location',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            if (addGardenMapState.isLoading)
              const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 16,
              right: 16,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    heroTag: 'zoomIn',
                    onPressed: () =>
                        ref.read(addGardenProvider.notifier).zoomIn(),
                    mini: true,
                    child: const Icon(Icons.zoom_in),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 16),
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    heroTag: 'zoomOut',
                    onPressed: () =>
                        ref.read(addGardenProvider.notifier).zoomOut(),
                    mini: true,
                    child: const Icon(Icons.zoom_out),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _showConfirmationDialog({
    required BuildContext context,
    required VoidCallback onSave,
    required VoidCallback onRedraw,
    required WidgetRef ref,
  }) async {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false, // User must tap a button to close the dialog
      builder: (BuildContext dialogContext) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Confirm Garden'),
          content: const SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Do you want to save this as your garden?'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('Redraw'),
              onPressed: () {
                onRedraw();
                GoRouter.of(dialogContext).pop(); // Close the dialog
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('Save'),
              onPressed: () async {
                final mapController =
                    ref.read(addGardenProvider.notifier).mapController;
                await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () async {
                  final Uint8List? snap = await mapController?.takeSnapshot();
                  if (snap != null) {
                    ref.read(addGardenProvider.notifier).setSnap(snap);
                  }
                });
                GoRouter.of(context).go(GardenDetailView.routeName);
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I tried various Screenshot Packages such as screenshot or davinci. They all seem to fail in taking a GoogleMap-Widget as Screenshot or I am using the wrong approach.

Comment: Please review the Google Maps Terms of Service to make sure that this use case is compliant. https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms. From what I know from previous cases, saving map tiles / taking screenshots for use outside of the service are not allowed. But please do seek legal advice if you want to make sure.

Comment: Okay. This may be the ToS, but why do they then have a built in 'takeScreenshot()'-method?

Comment: Please note of the use case of the `snapShot()` method from the official docs of the Maps SDK (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#public-final-void-snapshot-googlemap.snapshotreadycallback-callback) as the use cases as mentioned are usually for thumbnails within the app or snapshot on the notif center. Then from what I know, this method is only available in `google_maps_flutter` but not available in `google_maps_flutter_web`. I believe this is also not available in Maps JS. Were you able to reproduce the same issue on the Android runtime?

Comment: Thanks for the information.
Still my Use Case would be "Displaying a Screenshot of the Map as a Hero Section for the User". The user can then place fruit trees on the screenshot and therefore mark their position, etc. Seems like its not really serving the Use Case of a thumbnail or Notif-Preview.
Im working on mobile approach only atm. So no need to use `google_maps_flutter_web`.
Maybe there is an alternative to `google_maps_flutter` ?
For me it has the benefit of drawing polylines with a dev-friendly approach and having a satellite-view.

Comment: Probably implementing a live-view is then the better approach, since i think there is a possibilty to style individual markers..
It's just the thought of the target-user of the app, since the user will use the app probably on locations without a stable internet-connection...

Comment: Also checked out this example: (https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master_archive/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/snapshot.dart).
It produces the same white page with google sign and location-marker.
That makes me think of, this is not wanted by the Google_Maps-Devs.

Comment: That repository looks like an archived one. I tried running the sample app here: https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/snapshot.dart and the snapshot method seems to work fine on my end. Can you please make sure that you are passing correct credentials/api key?

Comment: I would also agree that you should just use a dynamic map instead of a static one (snapshot) since your use case seems to be inclined more for interactivity.